# How to use two different JQuery functions?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to html, css and jquery. Currently i'm trying to code my own website.
In my code I used two different jquery functions, but only one of them can work.
How can I edit my code so both of the functions will work?
Probably the answer is simple but i dont know how to get there yet..

My current jquery script:

```
<script>

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}
// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

// When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.top = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}


</script>
```

thank you so much.

Comment: You need to be a little more clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry! Im trying to make my navigation dissapear when im scrolling down and shown when im scrolling up.

Comment: And im trying to show a button after scrolling down which will take you to the top of the page again.

Comment: You're confused with jQuery and Vanilla

Comment: `only one of them can work` - what does this mean? Are you seeing errors? Edit your question, describe the problem in more detail. As it stands it is not clear what your problem or question is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your question. Here i am using initialisation inside that i am calling the other two functions also added two methods for doing that

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function(){
    init();
 });

 function init(){
   Function_one();
   Function_two();
 }

 function Function_one(){

 }
 function Function_two(){

 }
</script>
```

**(or)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready(function() {
       Function_one();
       Function_two();
});

     function Function_one(){

     }
     function Function_two(){

     }
    </script>
```